# Voice typing combined with special keys

Tags: voice, voice-recognition, google, dragon-naturallyspeaking

I am currently using google docs to do voice typing. The documents I am typing involve a lot of mathematical notation. Whenever there is something mathematical about to be typed, such as an equation, I usually just say the word "math" right before and "math" again when the mathematical piece has ended.
This is rather cumbersome though, and I would like to be able to just press a button on my keyboard at the beginning and end of a mathematical part. This doesn't work with google docs unless I stop what I am saying for a few seconds, wait for google's voice recognition software to finish transcribing what I said, and THEN type on my keyboard. This is too slow though.

Ideally I would just like to be able to press  a key, like say F12, which would then hotkeyed to automatically the word "math". Then I could use this along with voice typing seamlessly.

I am open to any software recommendations. I tried using Dragon (well, the free trial version on my phone), but it didn't work well at all with my voice. Or, if someone knows how to get this working with google's voice recognition software that would be great since google's software seems to work well with my voice.